# How do I prevent critters from chewing my sprinkler system?

Tags: sprinkler-system, pest-control

I have a lot of trees in my yard...and squirrels.  I'm not 100% sure the squirrels are the critters doing the damage, but it seems the most likely.  My neighbor says he's seen a possum in his yard before...and I'm not ruling out rats or mice.

Anyway, this is the third time this has happened. I hate to start killing squirrels to prevent it;  it's kind of fun looking at them scamper up and down my trees.  Plus, they might not be the offender anyway.

Here's what the damage looks like:

[image]

Comment: Is it not possible to bury your lines?

Comment: @randy - Yes, I had mulch covering them originally, but I haven't had time to put rain gutters up yet and when it rained the gradually got uncovered.  Need to bump that up the priority list.  Good suggestion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Weaponize some chili pepper oil by putting it in an atomizer or other spray bottle; proceed to spray the equipment.

Comment: I like this idea a lot, I'll give it a try.  Do you have any personal experience with this that proves that this will work?

Comment: You don't typically see critters chewing on pepper plants... [and the NPIC (National Pesticide Information Center)](http://npic.orst.edu/factsheets/Capsaicintech.pdf)

Comment: +1. This can also work for keeping rabbits and other nibblers out of gardens w/o a fence.